# What is wrong with this as3 piece of code?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, netstream

I'm an as3 newbie and I'm trying to send a message through netstream to a function that will handle it.

Here is the line that sends

```
  public function _attachLocalVideoAndAudio(muteCam:Boolean = false, muteMic:Boolean = 
  false):void
  {
   ...
    _outgoingStream.send("flagVideo",true);
   ...
   }


  public function flagV():Boolean
{
var client:Object;
client.flagVideo=function(flag:Boolean):void{
    check=flag;
}
return check;
}
```

*check is defined

I'm using Monster Debugger to debug and it seems that there is a problem with the inner function that handles the flag. There isn't much tutorials on the web on netstream.send() but I wrote this code based on something I saw online.

Comment: Is `check` variable function-wide or class-wide? Should be class-wide to ever work.

Comment: Yeah, it's class wide.